# Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type NSManagedObject

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift3, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm working on a Core Data project and I got a complier error for deleting item from a `TableViewController`:

Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type NSManagedObject

Here's the code:

```
var listArr:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Entity")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let listName = result.value(forKey: "listName") {
                    listArr.append(listName as! String)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // Handle error
        print(error)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "cellID"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = listArr[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        context.delete(listArr[indexPath.row]) //The error is here
        listArr.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete()` method that you're calling takes an `NSManagedObject` as its sole argument. You're passing in an element from your `listArr` array, which is an array of strings.

It seems obvious to say it, but if you want to delete a managed object, you need to tell Core Data which one to delete. It doesn't know what to do with a string.

I'm **guessing** (since you didn't say) that your `listArr` is made up of strings which are stored in Core Data as a property of an entity. You're fetching data somewhere and saving only the strings. That's fine **as long as your data store is read-only**, at least in this part of the app. You can display the strings but you can't go back and update Core Data, because you don't have the necessary information.

If that's true, what you should do is use an array of managed objects instead of an array of strings. When you need the string value, get it from one of the managed objects. When you need to delete an entry, delete that managed object.

Comment: After changing the array to [NSManagedObject], another error occurred, which is cast from NSManagedObject to unrelated type 'string' always fails, it's in the cellForRowAt indexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can populate a table from core-data.  Either you can use a `NSFetchedResultsController` that tracks changes from core data and keeps your data in sync. Or you can do a single fetch and store the values you want to display in our own datasource (such as an array).

With a `NSFetchedResultsController` you will get updates as your data changes.  With this model the correct way to delete a row is to delete it from core-data and wait for a callback from the `NSFetchedResultsController` to update your view.

With a single fetch (as you are doing) you do not get updates as core-data changes.  In this model you can simply remove the object from your array and update the view.  Updating core-data is another task unrelated to your view or datasource.  In this case you should use `persistentContainer` `performBackgroundTask` to fetch the object you want to delete and then delete it in the background.  For this to work you need to have a way to fetch the managedObject that you which to delete.  I don't know what kind of strings you are storing - but if they are unique you could use them for your fetch.  Otherwise you would also have to store some unique ID of the object such as it's objectID.